# Unable to let the user download PDF from web application

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

This is the controller class

```
@Controller
public class ReportController {
    @RequestMapping("/reports.htm")
    public void onSubmit(ModelMap map, HttpServletResponse response) {

        PayrollService ps = new PayrollServiceImpl();

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource jr = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ps.listAllLoans(), false);
        try {
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(new FileInputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\workspace\\payroll\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\payrollReports\\report2.jasper"), null, jr);
            JRExporter jre = new JRPdfExporter();
            jre.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "report.pdf");
            jre.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);

            ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
            jre.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output);
            jre.exportReport();

            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, A dialog box opens asking to download file, reports.htm, when I open the file, I get this

> ```
> %PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 3 0 obj <>stream xœ+är á26S°00SIár á
> ```
>
> ä2Rð‰*!ˆ´01RÉåÒw3T0²Ò¸44C²@jJ’s‘5Z*˜[ë™!t€t€å‹Ò¹4¼‹R‹@(¤c1,:H§€ƒÇCs3C<Ö˜êè*XX˜(8úe    p7E
>   endstream endobj 1 0 obj<>/Parent 4 0
>   R/Contents 3 0
>   R/Type/Page/Resources<>/Font<>>>/MediaBox[0
>   0 595 842]>> endobj 5 0 obj[1 0 R/XYZ
>   0 854 0] endobj 2 0 obj<> endobj 4 0
>   obj<> endobj 6 0 obj<> endobj 7 0
>   obj<> endobj 8 0 obj<>/Pages 4 0 R>>
>   endobj 9 0 obj<> endobj xref 0 10
>   0000000000 65535 f 0000000220 00000 n
>   0000000487 00000 n 0000000015 00000 n
>   0000000574 00000 n 0000000453 00000 n
>   0000000624 00000 n 0000000677 00000 n
>   0000000708 00000 n 0000000810 00000 n
>   trailer
>   <<9f3f4526709d5e33fd22d07da10c3883>]/Info
>   9 0 R/Size 10>> startxref 976 %%EOF

But when I save the file and open with adobe PDF, I get the correct PDF. 
How can I download reports.pdf instead of reports.htm?

Comment: Have you tried open the report with other browser?

Comment: Move your `.jasper` files outside of the web directory. If I can guess the name of the `.jasper` file, I can probably download it. If I can download it, I can see the SQL. If I can see the SQL, I have an attack vector on your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` headers to instruct the browser how to handle the resource.

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.pdf\"");
```

Comment: i tried this earlier, but used inline instead of attachment. Now i got it, thank you.